# DBPedia: What's the meaning of '__1' (double underscores) in URIs?

Tags: dbpedia

On DBPedia you can find a lot of URIs that containing double underscores and a number at the end, eg.:

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eric_Cheney__1
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eli_Wallach__1
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ed_Wood__1
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Francis_Ford_Coppola__1

Mostly these items are of the type [PersonFunction](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PersonFunction), but I can't find any documentation on *why* these objects exist (and a person's function isn't an ObjectProperty?)...

So why are these created?

Comment: I presume it would be that it has the same automatic URL, and so it tacks the `__1` on to ensure that it is unique. Naturally, that's nothing to do with why the objects themselves exist.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Thanks for your comment, but if you eg. check http://dbpedia.org/page/Ed_Wood and http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ed_Wood__1 its both about the same "Ed Wood", but I'd like to get to know and understand why the URI with "__1" exists and why, if it just represents the "person's function" it isn't a property of "Ed_Wood"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading [this DBPedia discussion on blank nodes storing](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03249.html), it seems the purpose is to avoid clashing with WikiPedia's URIs.

This, presumably, is used for nodes that don't have a corresponding article on WikiPedia, but rather points to a close article on the subject. As DBPedia tries to create a URI for everything, this URI is assembled according to specific rules (more on this can be found at the above linked discussion).

From the discussion:

> Note that intermediate node URIs always contain double underscores,
>   e.g. [1](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03249.html). Wikipedia doesn't allow consecutive underscores in page
>   titles, so we can be sure that these URIs will not clash with DBpedia
>   URIs for Wikipedia pages. We pick a name from the arguments of the
>   template from which the intermediate node is extracted, append two
>   underscores, that name and a number to the URI of the main page and
>   use that as the URI for the intermediate node. If there are multiple
>   intermediate nodes on one page for which we pick the same name, we use
>   different numbers, e.g. see [1](http://www.mail-archive.com/dbpedia-discussion@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03249.html) and [2].