# why is a sports "team" a "person" linked in dbpedia through a strict person-person query?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(?person1), ?person2
WHERE { 
   ?person1 ?p ?person2. 
   ?person1 a foaf:Person. 
   ?person2 a foaf:Person.
}
ORDER BY ?person1
LIMIT 1000
OFFSET 0
```

If you scroll down the results of the query here: http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

You'll see ice hockey teams etc. listed e.g.

```
:%C3%81g%C3%BAst_Hauksson   :Iceland_national_under-21_football_team
```

why are these people? How can I remove them?

I also get results like:

```
:%C3%84ngelholms_FF__Jakob_Augustsson__1    :Jakob_Augustsson 
:%C3%84ngelholms_FF__Joakim_Alriksson__1    :Joakim_Alriksson 
:%C3%84ngelholms_FF__Johan_Eiswohld__1  :Johan_Eiswohld
```

Which just reference the same person - is there a way to remove these sorts of self-references in the original query?

Comment: Because some non-persons are categorized as `foaf:Person`s, you might consider using the class `dbpedia-owl:Person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/Iceland_national_under-21_football_team is typed a `foaf:Person` (and `dbpedia-owl:Person` etc.), which is why it shows up in the result set.

Looking at the statements, I see that this resource is also a `dbpedia-owl:SportsTeamMember`, which is a subclass of `dbpedia-owl:Person`, which is an `owl:equivalentClass` of `foaf:Person`. This shows how the sports team was inferred to be a person.

The information in DBpedia is extracted from Wikipedia using templates, as described [here](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/How_to_edit_DBpedia_Mappings). In general, mapping templates map the information in Wikipedia infoboxes and other templates to DBpedia resource properties. An article having a certain infobox (or for other mappings, a 'normal' template) are then said to be of a specific RDF class.
For example, the [Infobox football club](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Mapping_en:Infobox_football_club) mapping template maps creates resources of type `dbpedia-owl:SoccerClub` from articles that have this infobox. (This doesn't apply to the Iceland team, though.)

It looks like the mapping [Football squad player](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Mapping_en:Football_squad_player) may have been responsible for the assertion that the Iceland team is typed a person. The template is used to list the team players, but the version of the Wikipedia page used to create the DBpedia resource has typos that could have broken the process. I'm not completely sure, but it may explain why not all national football teams are typed `foaf:Person`.

You can't remove specific statements from DBpedia, but you can correct errors in the source Wikipedia article, or correct, update or create mappings for DBpedia.

To remove self references, you can add a `FILTER` statement to your `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE { 
    ?person1 ?p ?person2. 
    ?person1 a foaf:Person. 
    ?person2 a foaf:Person.
    FILTER (?person1 != ?person2).
}
```

If you are looking for specific types of relations between pairs of `foaf:Person`s, you can of course specify them:

```
WHERE {
  ...
  ?person1 foaf:knows ?person2.
  ...
}
```

Edit 2: I later realised you were asking for a different type of self-reference. From [DBPedia: What's the meaning of '__1' (double underscores) in URIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909369/dbpedia-whats-the-meaning-of-1-double-underscores-in-uris) I understand these are URIs for intermediate nodes, created to avoid having to use blank nodes. For example, `:%C3%84ngelholms_FF__Jakob_Augustsson__1` is the (prefixed) URI for Jakob Augustsson within (the description of) `:%C3%84ngelholms_FF`. For the football example, you could add `FILTER (?p != dbpedia-owl:currentMember)` to exclude these results.

Edit 1: added a few hyperlinks.